# MS Access Asynchronous Queries

Tags: sql, ms-access, asynchronous, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a basic `SELECT` query fired from an Access form that takes a while to execute, so I would like to run the query asynchronously and allow my users to continue using the form (or at least keep them updated on the progress).

The problem is that Access freezes the application when code is being executed, appearing to the users to have crashed - even to the point of Windows marking it 'Not Responding' and offering to kill it. Obviously not very user-friendly! I have tried using the code listed on the MSDN [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/262311) and a variant method [here](http://bytes.com/topic/access/insights/905648-asynchronous-query).

Both these solutions do seem to run the query 'asynchronously' (the code block firing the async query completes, and the `rs_FetchProgress` and `rs_FetchComplete` events (or `cn_ExecuteComplete` event in the second solution) fire and run... but Access's interface still locks up until the query is done executing. Calling `Repaint` and `DoEvents` in various places (such as the `rs_FetchProgress` event) does not seem to have any effect.

I doubt it's relevant information, but the view being `SELECT`ed from is in SQL Server, the view doesn't return a huge amount of data but does take about 20 seconds to process.

Comment: Did you try using `DoEvents`

Comment: I haven't worked with Access for a while, but there used to be a "pass-through" option where the back-end would execute the full query, including the joins and filtering by the where-condition. When pass-through mode is NOT used, Access brings a lot of data from the  back-end over the wire, and performs much work client-side, and that behavior appears to be synchronous.

Comment: I did, peppered it about in various places with `Repaint`. Didn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: VBA is single-threaded, so whatever asynchronisity ADO provides, what your Access app can make of that is questionable. That said, take a look at this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/194960

Comment: @Tim Tried using a passthrough query, but no avail unfortunately

Comment: And you're sure the view is responding quickly when a select is issued against it server-side?

Comment: OK, I see you say below the view takes a long time to process.

Answer (score 1):

Do not pull a huge recordset when you open the form.   Base the form on a query which pulls only a few or even no records when it first loads.  Then give the users a method to select a different reasonably-sized subset of records.

Try to avoid pulling huge recordsets regardless of whether your data source is a linked Access table or a client-server database.

Comment: There's not a huge recordset to pull - the query only returns around 80 records. It's selecting from a view that takes a relatively long time to process (performing various aggregates on a larger recordset)

Comment: OK, I didn't get that from your question.  I've not encountered a situation like that.  Assuming you've exhausted all options to optimize the view, think I would try opening the form with a single row of dummy values.  Then in a later event (load or current), open the ADO recordset async and useclient.  When that is fully populated, assign it as the form's recordset.  But I don't know if will be enough to eliminate the "not responding" issue.  It might prove to be just as unsuitable as what you have now.